# I have list which have keys of dictionary. How to access the dictionary using these keys dynamically

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have list which have keys of dictionary. How to access the dictionary using these keys dynamically. e.g

```
key_store = ['test','test1']

mydict = {"test":{'test1':"value"},"test3":"value"}
```

So how to access `mydict` using `key_store` I want to access `mydict['test']['test1']`.

Note: `key_store` store depth of keyword means it have keywords only its value will be dictionary like test have dictionary so it have 'test','test1'

Comment: What wiill required output for above Test Case?

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion:

```
def get_value(d, k, i):
    if not isinstance(d[k[i]], dict):
        return d[k[i]]
    return get_value(d[k[i]], k, i+1)
```

The parameters are the dictionary, the list and an index you'll be running on.

The stop condition is simple; Once the value is not a dictionary, you want to return it, otherwise you continue to travel on the dictionary with the next element in the list.

---

```
>>> key_store = ['test','test1']
>>> Dict = {"test":{'test1':"value"},"test3":"value"}
>>> def get_value(d, k, i):
...     if isinstance(d[k[i]], str):
...         return d[k[i]]
...     return get_value(d[k[i]], k, i+1)
...
>>> get_value(Dict, key_store, 0)
'value'
```

Comment: @user3048148 You're welcome. Don't just "check", it's more important to try to understand.

Comment: Also note that in my solution I expect the "path" (the list) leads to a value that's a string.

Comment: Having to specify the iteration index `i` is not very nice, IMHO. Also, I don't really get the stopping criteria, since nothing in the question makes me assume that the value is a string. Wouldn't it be much better to check for a `dict` and stop if it's not?

Comment: @HannesOvrén sure it's better.. I wrote the answer as hint for OP. He can fine tune it as he wish. Will edit as soon as I'll get free time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple for-loop.

```
def get_nested_key(keypath, nested_dict):
    d = nested_dict
    for key in keypath:
        d = d[keypath]
    return d

>>> get_nested_key(('test', 'test1'), Dict)
```

Add error checking as required.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a simple dictionary reduce:

```
>>> mydict = {"test": {'test1': "value"}, "test3": "value"}
>>> print reduce(dict.get, ['test', 'test1'], mydict)
value
```

Comment: I like this! Only problem seems to be that if the key does not exist, you will get `None` as a result instead of a `KeyError`, which I would think is the most obvious response to that mistake. You can't differentiate between the value of the key being `None` and the key not existing.

Comment: Agreed.  It's not clear to me what the desired behavior is between for those edge cases.  It could be changed to `reduce(dict.__getitem__, ['test', 'test1'], mydict)` and then it will raise an error both when the key doesn't exist (e.g. `['test', 'test2']`) and when it's trying to look up on a value (e.g. `['test', 'test1', 'value']`) albeit different errors.  It could also be changed to `reduce(lambda x, y: x[y] if isinstance(x, dict) else None, ['test', 'test1'], mydict)` to return None in both cases.